# Windows shares not reconnecting

Tags: 16.04, windows, fstab, cifs

I have the following entry in my `fstab`

```
//myserver/media  /NAS/media/  cifs  credentials=/root/.windows,iocharset=utf8  0  0
```

and I can mount such share with

```
sudo mount /NAS/media
```

Unfortunately, it does not mount automatically.

How to make it mount automatically on reboot, re-login, wi-fi reconnect etc.

Answer (score 0):

First make sure your have cifs-utils installed. Its not installed by default - god knows why.

sudo apt install cifs-utils

Then you might want to try to add uid and gid. If you are the first user it would be 1000 for both. If that is not enough, try the sec=ntlm

```
//myserver/media  /NAS/media/  cifs  credentials=/root/.windows,uid=1000,gid=1000,iocharset=utf8,sec=ntlm  0  0
```

Sometimes I find that it does not work. I guess networking system is up too late for fstab, but when I run

sudo mount -a

it connects.

Help it helps
CatMan